# Restart level Ontrigger after a duration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to restart a level when a character enters a Trigger (which is the end of a race) after  5 or 10 seconds.

I have a script that look like this :

```
public class WinBox : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera Camera1;
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    { 
        GameObject.Find("Camera (eye)").SendMessage("StopTimer");
    }
}
```

What should I add to make the level restart after the time that I want to define?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do something after a delay you could make an utility function like this:

```
static class Utils 
{
    public static IEnumerator DoAfterDelay(float delay, System.Action callback) 
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        callback();
    }
}
```

And then call it with StartCoroutine Like this

```
private void RestartLevel() 
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{ 
    GameObject.Find("Camera (eye)").SendMessage("StopTimer");
    float secondsUntilRestart = 10;
    StartCoroutine(Utils.DoAfterDelay(secondsUntilRestart, RestartLevel));
}
```

From my experience, you often need this `DoAfterDelay` functionality, that's why I'd place it in a separate class instead of making it a local, private method

Comment: Thanks it works great ! 
I had to add "  using UnityEngine.SceneManagement; " at the top of my script btw for the Scene Manager to work

Answer (score 3):

You can use [coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) to delay the call of the [SceneManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html).[LoadScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) function, along with the [GetActiveScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene.html) function to get the information about the current scene :

```
private IEnumerator RestartSceneAfterDelay( float delay = 10f )
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds( delay );
    SceneManager.LoadScene( SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex ) ;
}
```

And call the function as follow :

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{ 
    GameObject.Find("Camera (eye)").SendMessage("StopTimer");

    StartCoroutine( RestartSceneAfterDelay() ) ;
    // OR
    StartCoroutine( RestartSceneAfterDelay(5f) ) ;      
}
```

---

An other solution (but not as good as the first one) is to use the [Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) function to delay the call to the Scene manager. Though, avoid this way because the call to the function is made from a string, which is hard to debug afterwards.

```
private void RestartScene()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene( SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex ) ;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{ 
    GameObject.Find("Camera (eye)").SendMessage("StopTimer");

    Invoke( "RestartScene", 5f ) ;
}
```